# Why is my SQL server not working right(android SDK)?

Tags: android, sql

I did the notepad tutorials and my SQL server is a modified version of that. For some reason my app is not writing to it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I dont understand what part of the code is wrong.

```
    package com.drawing;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotesDbAdapter {

 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_X = "x";
public static final String KEY_Y = "y";
public static final String KEY_Size = "size";
private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
          " create table " +  DATABASE_TABLE  + " ("
         + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,  "
         + KEY_X + " text not null, "
         + KEY_Y + " text not null, "
         + KEY_Size + " text not null);"; 

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("dbAdapter", e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db); 
        }

    }

    public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    public long createNote(float f, float g, int size) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_X, f);
        initialValues.put(KEY_Y, g);
        initialValues.put(KEY_Size, size);
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }


    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_X,KEY_Y,KEY_Size}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_X,KEY_Y,KEY_Size}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, int x, int y, int size) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_X, x);
        args.put(KEY_Y, y);
        args.put(KEY_Size, size);
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message, does the code fail or...?

Comment: It says "Error inserting into table 'notes'". Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Is it possible to see the INSERT generated for that? Are you certain the table is created? Does any of the other calls - ie. SELECT work?

Comment: As far as I can tell the other calls like open are working, how would I make sure the table is created?

Comment: Doesn't your code just insert values into `_id`? Are you putting data in the other fields? Since they are set to not null, the call will fail unless you ensure that the fields get values?

Comment: Wait, so _id is the field? Thanks, I thought the KEY_xyz were the different fields or columns. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is initiated here:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";     
public static final String KEY_X = "_id";     
public static final String KEY_Y = "_id";     
public static final String KEY_Size = "_id";
```

I would guess it should be more like in the question I link to:

```
public static final String KEY_BOOK = "book"; 
public static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author"; 
public static final String KEY_ISBN = "isbn"; 
public static final String KEY_RATING = "rating"; 
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
```

Second, your table creation also seems wrong:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            " create table " +  DATABASE_TABLE  + " (" 
                     + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,  "
                     + KEY_X + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                     + KEY_Y + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                     + KEY_Size + " integer primary key autoincrement, ";
```

You have created all fields as primary key and autoincrement - that doesn't really make sense. Again looking at the other question:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
      " create table " +  DATABASE_TABLE  + " ("
     + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,  "
     + KEY_AUTHOR + " text not null, "
     + KEY_BOOK + " text not null, "
     + KEY_ISBN + " text not null, "
     + KEY_RATING + " text not null);";
```

This makes much more sense.

Please take a closer look at the question below - and re-read the tutorials you have started with.

[I keep getting the SQLException error with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560657/i-keep-getting-the-sqlexception-error-with-this)

The question here may have problems, but seem to identify the columns properly (which is where you seem to have problems). The answers go through some other steps - and I recommend that you take a look at the 'Related' suggestions here on the right side of your own question. You may find more pointers to lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I looked as a few of them, yet I'm still getting the same error. New code in OP

Comment: Insert your code in the question, overwrite the old if you feel that's more appropriate.

Comment: It's there, sorry I was having trouble at first, forgot I had to highlight then ctrl-k.

Comment: I changed it again, still same error, thanks though I'll add it to the OP

Comment: anyone else have any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having the same issue: you need to reinitialize the columns like Anders showed above and change the database version so onUpgrade runs, thanks all.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Have been away and unable to reply until now.